# Calculate if 2 or more dates overlap

Tags: php, algorithm

Is there an efficient way of calculating whether 2 or more dates overlap in PHP?

Ex.

- **Date1:** Start1 = 2012-03-10 / End1 = 2012-05-10
- **Date2:** Start2 = 2012-04-25 / End2 = 2012-06-01
- **Date3:** Start3 = 2012-07-15 / End3 = 2012-08-20

In the example above Date1 and Date2 overlaps, Date3 is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format then you can just do a **string comparison** (they dont have to be valid dates either OR after 1970 if using strtotime() for unix timestamps)

```
if( ($date1['start']>=$date2['start'] && $date1['start']<=$date2['end']) || ($date1['end']>=$date2['start'] && $date1['end']<=$date2['end']) || ($date1['start']<=$date2['start'] && $date1['end']>=$date2['end']) )
{
    // overlap
}
```

this checks if start or end of date1 is between the start and end of date2 OR if date1 surrounds date2

.

thanks to @Germann-Arlington -

```
if($date1['start']<=$date2['end'] && $date2['start']<=$date1['end']) { // overlap }
```

Comment: thanks to @Germann-Arlington - if($date1['start']<=$date2['end'] && $date2['start']<=$date1['end']) { // overlap }

Comment: this seems good, but what about more than 2 dates? I'd like to avoid nested for cycles if possible...

Comment: this depends on your requirements but a single function to compare 2 dates is the starting point. If you have 3 dates, then compare 1 and 2 gives overlap (marking both). Then you need to compare 3 with 1 (no overlap) so check against 2 (no overlap). You do need to cycle through the combinations, but end the current cycle if an overlap exists.

Comment: give us the format of the source data and how you want to be notified of the overlap and we can write a function to perform your check. ie array(0=>array('start'=>'2012-03-10','end'=>'2012-05-10','overlap=>false), 1=>array()....);

Answer (score 1):

If you have bunch of dates (as I understand the problem) you can use an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), and convert the dates to integers (The [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) can be used)

Comment: You can only convert to unix time if the dates are after epoch (1970-01-01) AND its not necessary as the dates are in MySQL style so just compare as a string

Comment: @Waygood Converting to integers is expected to be more efficient (in both time and space) if we are dealing with large data bases. But yes, a lexical compare on strings can also be used. The main issue in this answer is the interval tree usage, if there are multiple intervals.